# How to disable autoscroll in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I'm using a **Toshiba Satellite L305d-s5895** laptop with Windows 7. Every time I visit a page, it automatically scrolls to the bottom of the page. Even when I scroll up again, it will start to scroll back to the bottom. I am using the built-in touchpad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with Windows 7. The autoscroll feature is part of the touchpad's software/drivers. Look in your system tray for [`Synaptics`](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers) or similar application. From there, you may find the setting to turn off autoscroll.

Answer (score 1):

Synaptics apparently has changed their software to provide this auto-scroll feature.  There is no visible means of disabling, you may go to Mouse settings in Control Panel and set it to slow (under device settings-Scroll).